# Send To connection in Content Organizer Moving document Instead of Copying

Tags: 2010, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule, send-to-destination

I followed the [This Link](http://www.dreamsharepoint.com/content-organizer-moving-files/), which states to configure a "Send To" function for moving a file from one document library to another at the destination URL specified.

As shown in the image I have selected the Send To action as "Copy",but still it moves the document to the destination.

Is there any way by which I can prevent the move and make it Copy.

Is there any way by which the document gets copied to the destination site instead of moving?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you select "Copy" option when you were creating a send to connection in Central Administration. Because when you select "Copy" and perform the send to action for copying the list items or documents. It does not leave the link of the destination url of the document. But in case of "Move & Leave a Link" it leaves the link of the destination document, when we click on the respective item or document. You may refer to the following links,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/configure-send-to-connections-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Yes I did selected the Copy option for the Send To. I dont want to leave a link. I want a copy of that document to get stored in the source drop-off library

Comment: So it is leaving the link. Check your retention policies, check the content organizer rules you've written on that site,list. Because in case of copy it doesn't leave the link when we click on the document.

Comment: it neither leaving a link nor a copy, its just moving the document to the destination. I checked everything